# ion-back-button not showing without defaultHref

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm using angular's own routing `this.router.navigate(['/locaties']);`. When I navigate forward it still doesn't show up. What am I doing wrong?

toolbar.component.html

```html
<ion-toolbar color="primary">
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
    <ion-back-button slot="start"></ion-back-button>
  </ion-buttons>

  <ion-title> {{ _toolbarTitle | async }} </ion-title>

  <img slot="end" src="assets/specto_logo.svg" />
</ion-toolbar>
```

Comment: Is it visible if you put defaultHref?

Comment: @iamentafaz yes it is but it always directs me to the defaulthref then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because there is nothing on the ionic history stack. In order to have it show you must use the ionic controller.

```
this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/locaties');
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/

https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-navigation-and-routing-ultimate-guide

Comment: Isn't navCtrl deprecated in favour of router.navigate?